# Old Admob download links for iOS

Tags: ios, admob, marmalade

I develop mobile app for iOS with Marmalade SDK.
Marmalade SDK does not support iOS 6 right now.
I need older version of Admob iOS SDK. (I believe I need Admob 6.1 for iOS)

Update:-

GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.1.4.zip 
Do anyone know original SHA1 Checksum for that fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found

http://dl.google.com/googleadmobadssdk/googleadmobadssdkios_udid.zip

It seems to me GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS‑6.1.5.zip   SHA1 139ed5a9c2d8baa464d50b7f87adad7d07f367ec

I hope it will work

GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS‑6.1.4.zip   SHA1 3b4bebc13e369a5312de5e1004864e26ecc17d6c

If you have GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS‑6.1.4.zip please share link and I will make your answer as correct. Thank You!

GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS‑6.1.4.zip - seems like does not use UDID I believe it is safer t use.